# MySQL Value in column is not returned in PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
require("config.inc.php");

$query = "Select * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$query_params = array(
                      ':username' => $_POST['username']
                      );

$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

error--> $estado2 = $rows[0]['estado'];

$query = "Select * FROM dogs WHERE adocao = 'Sim' AND estado = $estado2 ";
```

I need variable returned from the table to make a new query

However, my variable `$estado2` does not return the right value

Already used in this way and it worked

Please, Help

Comment: `"my variable $estado2 does not return the right value"` - Then what *does* it return?  What is the value of `$estado2` when this executes?  What is the resulting SQL query?  Also note that your second query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  You should be using parameters (just like you do in your first query).

Comment: What is the datatype of `estado`?

Comment: unfortunately I can not know the result because I am working on android, and communicating via POST by Json where I get a username and take the state corresponding to it in the database ,

Comment: Why fetch all the resulting rows when you only use anything from the first one? But anyway, if you do _print_r($rows);_ what is output? Does the username you search for exist on the table

Comment: Why are you doing two queries instead of joining them into one? `SELECT d.* FROM dogs AS d JOIN users AS u ON d.estado = u.estado WHERE d.adocao = 'Sim' AND u.username = :username`

Comment: estado this is  Varchar and $estado2 is a string

Comment: If $estado2 is a string then it needs quotes around it when you do the 2nd query (or better use parameters in the 2nd query)

Comment: Because I just use the first query to fetch in the collun estado value in the database

The second query and which really need

Comment: That doesn't stop you using a single query,

Comment: and true, but the problem is in Variable $ state and not in the query because only this time it is not working

Comment: To have any hope of figuring this out we need the see what is output when you _print_r($row);_ as previously asked for.

Comment: As I am working on android hum print this page I will give no output Some

Comment: Then you will need to knock up a dummy page to call this script and output the results.

Comment: Could you give me an example of this Dumb Script PHP please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a join you can do this:

```
require("config.inc.php"); 
$query = "Select * FROM users LEFT JOIN dogs as d ON estado = d.estado WHERE username = :username AND d.adocao = 'Sim'";

$query_params = array(
                  ':username' => $_POST['username']
                  );

$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

while ($rows = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    $estado = $rows['estado'];
}
```

Or the way you're doing it:

```
require("config.inc.php"); 
$query = "Select * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$query_params = array(
                  ':username' => $_POST['username']
                  );

$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
$rows = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$estado2 = $rows['estado'];

$query = "Select * FROM dogs WHERE adocao = 'Sim' AND estado = :estado";

$query_params = array(
                  ':estado' => $estado2
                  );

$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

$dogs = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Not sure if estado is an int or string so I passed it through as a binded param.

Comment: did not work unfortunately no solution , yet does not return the correct value

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle for your table and some of the values?  That SQL would work.  There's no reason for it to return an incorrect value for what's in the db.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Works, i changed my Java Class